# XCode 7 Property is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Now I am using the XCode 7. But sometimes controller property windows is empty. In these situation I need to restart the pc. Then only it is showing the property. Anyone know the solution.  (In this picture I selected the label, button and viewcontroller)

[image]

Comment: that sometimes happened even with Xcode 6. Storyboard reopening did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the solution. Just close storyboard and clear the drivedata then it is showing. But I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this a few times. I always went to launchscreen.storyboard and it usually helped. If not, try restarting Xcode (or even your computer). Sometimes I had to do all of this a few times to make the inspectors show again.